# A doubt about Exercise 12 in textbook Algebra by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm doing **Exercise 12** in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> For $T \subset G$ and fixed $a \in G$ show that the assignment $g T \mapsto a g T$ is a permutation $h_{a}: G / T \rightarrow G / T$ on the set $G / T$ of right cosets of $T$ in $G$.

IMHO, for the map $g T \mapsto a g T$ to be well-defined, it must be the case that $gT=hT \implies agT = ahT$. This means $gh^{-1} \in T \implies (ag)(ah)^{-1} \in T$, or equivalently $gh^{-1} \in T \implies agh^{-1}a^{-1} \in T$. This means $T$ is a normal subgroup.

Could you please confirm that for the exercise to be true, we need stronger hypothesis, i.e. $T$ is a normal subgroup?

Comment: You’ve got the conditions for equality wrong. $gT=hT$ if and only if $g^{-1}h\in T$, not $gh^{-1}\in T$.

Comment: This is weird. $gT$ is a **left** coset, not a right coset as the text claims. If you were acting on right cosets, you would need the action to be something like $Tg\mapsto Tga^{-1}$ (so the action is associative). But in any case, it’s the equality condition that you’ve got wrong, and when you use the correct equality condition, you’ll see that the problem is in fact true.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my logical misunderstanding @ArturoMagidin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  @Arturo Magidin's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list. All credits are given to @Arturo Magidin.

> You’ve got the conditions for equality wrong. $gT=hT$ if and only if $g^{-1}h\in T$, not $gh^{-1}\in T$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very useful information @user1729. I should have know this option before. I can accept my own answer, instead of waiting for 2 days.